# How to increase memsql stmt cache

Tags: singlestore

I'm using memsql 5.0.8 community version. I just randomly get the `ER_STMT_CACHE_FULL` error, All I can do is reboot the server. How can I increase it.

Comment: MemSQL doesn't raise this error message (We don't have a stmt cache).   Which client are you using (python, php, etc.)?

Comment: @Adam Prout Nodejs Sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

MemSQL doesn't have a statement cache and never generates this error. You are likely running your application against MySQL or MariaDB

Comment: Actually i use both of it. When I switch to MySQL, The Error disappeared. I think it's because of Sequelize. Cause When I query directly against memsql using MySQLWorkbench,  It gives me a different error: an error occured, failed to codegen.(I don't remember exactly what the error is, cause I haven't got it for days)